# Difference between Bluetooth and iBeacon protocols in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am integrating an iOS app with a Bluetooth chip.
I am trying to understand the differences between a *constant BLE connection* and an *iBeacon* notifications in terms of the protocol.

So I am able to connect to the chip and send/recieve data from/to iPhone.

To **communicate** , you need 3 things :

1. name
2. service UUID
3. characteristic UUID (to write and read from).

Then, when you want to register to a region of an `iBeacon`, you also need a `UUID` of the `characteristic`, but also `major/minor` values.

Thing is, all `iBeacon` apps will not detect this type of broadcast- the one I use for communication.

So, whats basically the difference in the protocol? what if I keep advertising the same service/char I use for regular communication? is it good also for beacon push notification ? apparently not- but whats the different?

Also, I have 2 hardware chips, both will not let you set a major/minor values, but only to update the characteristic to notify a new value to subscribers which is hex (not an integer like major/minor) - **is that equivalent to an iOS push notification by iBeacon detection ??**

Answer (score 2):

**Difference between constant BLE connection and Beacons**

A "constant BLE connection" is a connection, two devices pair with each other.

A BLE `iBeacon` device does not know about other devices. It simply broadcasts a certain signal frequently. Other devices can than listen to this signal and evaluate the signals strength to estimate how nearby the sender might be.

> "Is it equivalent to Push Notifications?"

No.

**Major & Minor**

The major number (2 bytes) is used to group a related set of beacons. For example, all beacons in my flat will have the same major number, while the neighbour uses his own.  That way the application know in which specific flat the application is.

The minor number (2 bytes) is used to identify the actual beacon. Each beacon in my flat has a different minor number, so that you know where within my flat the application is.

> " value to subscribers ... is hex ... not an integer"

An hexadecimal *is an* integer.

**HowTo**

You need to insert a specific set of bytes into the optional manufacturer specific Data field (your "new value" for subscribers).

According to [this site](https://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi), you need the following values:

```
ID (uint8_t)
Data Length (uint8_t) - The number of bytes in the rest of the payload = 0x15
128-bit UUID (uint8_t[16]) - The 128-bit ID identifying the Beacons manufacturer 
Major (uint16_t) - The major value
Minor (uint16_t) - The minor value
TX Power (uint8_t) - This value is used to try to estimate distance based on the RSSI value
```

Example [from this site](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-diy-ibeacon-raspberry-pi/):

```
 0x02 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 00 00 00 00 C8 00
```

`0x02`

`0x0008`

`1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15` Manufacturer

`00 00` Major

`00 00` Minor

`C8 00` Power

Comment: Thanks a lot , thats i already know, that wasn't the questions.

Comment: I misunderstood than. Please re-phrase the question for shallow thought-ed people like me: What exactly is your question?